# Error creating runtime object of type System.Drawing.Point

Tags: c#, gettype

I want to create a object of type `System.Drawing.Point` at runtime, I tried to use the code below:

```
String typename = "System.Drawing.Point";
Type tp = Type.GetType(typename);
Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);
```

But I always get `tp == null`. But, for example if I use `System.Double` everything is ok.

Comment: Is `System.Drawing.dll` loaded?

Comment: What platform is this for? For example, Silverlight doesn't have access to that type.

Comment: The typename needs to be assembly-qualified, anyway, I believe.

Comment: @J.Steen: Depends on the platform. For full .NET you can get by with just the full name. On Core-CLR (like Silverlight) you need to assembly qualified name.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Just tried it in full .NET. Didn't work without assembly qualification.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just checking now; it's been a while since I've had to load types without using their assembly qualified names. I think YK1 has got what I'm thinking (works for mscorelib types, but not others)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yeah. The documentation states you need the assembly qualification except for those specific exceptions. You do NOT need the full version qualification, however, if you've got the right assembly referenced. But it's probably prudent to include it. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [qualify the assembly in your type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx), so

```
String typename = "System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing";
```

will work (if System.Drawing.dll is referenced and loaded).

> typeName
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. [..] If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Type.GetType will try to load the type from mscorlib. Use assembly-qualified name of the type.

```
String typename = "System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";

Type tp = Type.GetType(typename);
```

Comment: Probably more prudent to include the version info, even if it's not strictly necessary to make the code work. +1. =)

Comment: Where on Earth did you get that PublicKeyToken value from?  It is b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't that... what it says?

Comment: It said something else before :)  Still curious where he got the b1... value.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, I had typed incorrect token initially. But immediately corrected the mistake. You probably have the older version of my answer. apologies.

Comment: @HansPassant Ahhh. I never saw that version. =D

Comment: I like to believe that Hans has the PublicKeyToken values memorized for all standard .NET assemblies.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You mean there's a possibility he doesn't?

Comment: @J.Steen: [He's more machine now than man...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONdLEqzhXOI)